# BCrypt authentication failing

Tags: spring-security, bcrypt

I am trying to implement BCrypt password encryption using Spring Security.  For some reason the password validation is failing for what should be a valid password.  The password was created in the same app, and passes the authentication check when I hard code it in a unit test.  But, for some reason when it is running on the server it fails.  I have checked that it's using the same JRE, the same number of iterations (stored in the hash).  I tried reducing it to the bare minimum of code to figure out what's wrong.  I am stuck at the point where this statement:

```
BCrypt.checkpw("password123", "$2a$10$kyRMcxNqagw.ny369X4AsumV4cvHt4Usfvm.rGNDRnxP2SLKioFhu")
```

returns true when run in a unit test, but fails when run in my PasswordEncoder live on the server.  Any ideas on why this is failing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake.  At one point our code was converting passwords to uppercase.  I removed it some places, but missed one.  So comparing all caps password to mixed case password failed (as one would expect it should).